# Как добавить кнопку поверх Изображения в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Делаю свой сайт, пытаюсь наложить сверху на контейнер сайта кнопку для перехода на другую страницу, но какие методы бы не использовал, ни как не получается. Перерыл весь интернет ничего не помогает. Не могли бы вы подсказать как правильно это сделать?

Вот пример моего кода страницы

CSS я пока что не трогал

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar-nav sticky-top shadow">
    <img src="image/one/2.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Шапка">
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="image/one/5.png" class="img img-fluid w-100" alt="Колонка 1" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Подробнее</button> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <img src="image/one/3.png" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Колонка 2">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в css задать родительскому div:

```
position: relative;
```

а кнопке:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: В целом помогло, только пришлось добавить ещё расположение к кнопке right: 100px; bottom: 100px; . Спасибо за помощь